# malloc and free of a char-array

Tags: beginner, c, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

I wrote a function to reverse a char-array (string).
Since I'm beginner and didn't work with `malloc` and stuff before, maybe someone could take a look, if this is fine, what I'm doing here?

```
char* reverse_string(char* string)
{
    // getting actual length of the string
    size_t length = strlen(string);

    // allocate some space for the new string
    char* new_string = malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));

    // index for looping over the string
    int actual_index = 0;

    // iterating over the string until '\0'
    while(string[actual_index] != '\0') 
        new_string[length-actual_index-1] = string[actual_index++];

    // setting the last element of string-array to '\0' 
    new_string[length] = '\0';

    // free up the allocated memory
    free(new_string);

    // return the new string
    return new_string;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Fix the bug

Once memory is freed, it should not be referenced again.  Unfortunately, your code allocates memory and then frees it and then returns a pointer to the freed memory.  That's a serious bug!  To fix it, simply omit the `free` within the function and make sure the caller calls `free` instead.  Alternatively, you could avoid all of that by reversing the passed string in place.

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `strlen` which means that it should `#include <string.h>` and `malloc` and `free` which means that it should `#include <stdlib.h>`.  It was not difficult to infer, but it helps reviewers if the code is complete.

### Use `const` where practical

In your `revere_string` routine, the string passed into the function is not and should not be altered.  You should indicate that fact by declaring it like this:

```
char* reverse_string(const char* string)
```

### Check for `NULL` pointers

The code must avoid dereferencing a NULL pointer if the call to `malloc` fails.  The only indication that it has failed is if `malloc` returns `NULL`; if it does, it would probably make most sense to immediately return that NULL pointer.

### Learn to use pointers instead of indexing

Using pointers effectively is an important C programming skill.  This code could be made much simpler by doing an in-place reversal of the passed string and by using pointers:

```
char* reverse_string(char* string) {
    if (string == NULL) 
        return string;
    char *fwd = string;
    char *rev = &string[strlen(string)-1];

    while (rev > fwd) {
        char tmp = *rev;
        *rev-- = *fwd;
        *fwd++ = tmp;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your review. learned a lot of new things with it :)